# URLScan and percent signs

Tags: security, iis, urlscan, web-application-firewall

So I just ran into a stupid problem in which users could not download files that had a percent sign in it.  This is an IIS6/Win2k3 box.  It wound up being URLScan.  I had to un-set two things in urlscan.ini:

> 1) Set VerifyNormalization to 0 (disabled)
>   2) Remove the percent sign from the "DenyUrlSequences" section

Do an iisreset, and problem solved.  But the big question is: How much of a security risk is this?

Answer (score 0):

Percent signs are used in URL encoding and could be used to express nasty chars such as Quote Marks.  This rejection may be due to NormalizeUrlBeforeScan being on or off,  I would try flipping this setting.

UrlScan isn't a very good WAF and its likely that you will run into problems with other false positives/false negatives.   Mod_Security is more mature and can be used with IIS however it involves running a reverse proxy which to be honest is a bit of mess but IMHO its a better mess than UrlScan.

If you have some spare gold bricks you should pick up [Cisco ACE](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/prod/collateral/contnetw/ps5719/ps9586/data_sheet_c78-458627.html),  it is a good WAF.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with processing of unfiltered URI character entities as URI strings can be used as vehicles for code injection.